# How to handle a TCP client dropping out and re-connecting

Tags: python, c++, sockets, tcp

I have been struggling for some time with this issue.  I have a TCP server running in c++ that has essentially two states, the first is Listening were it will run for sometime and listen for a connection, then sleep for a little.  If it detects a connection then it will begin sending information off a queue and listening for incoming information.  If it detects a "*" then it will call close() on the client, and begin listening for a reconnect again.  My issue is when this happens and the client attempts to reconnect it does not work.  Calling accept on the c++ server returns -1, while the python client successfully connects but receives an infinite amount of empty characters.  Am I missing a step on closing the connection? or is their a setsockopt I need?

Here is the setting up of the server socket

> ```
> //We want to ignore SIGPIP error and handle them manualy
> signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
> ```

```
//SEt up a timout of 5 milliseconds for sending a recieveing
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = 0;
timeout.tv_usec = 5;

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port_num);
std::string devname = "wlan0";
setsockopt(m_Socket.GetData(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, devname.c_str(), strlen(devname.c_str()));
setsockopt(m_Socket.GetData(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char* )&timeout, sizeof(timeout));
setsockopt(m_Socket.GetData(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char* )&timeout, sizeof(timeout));
if (bind(m_Socket.GetData(), (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
    std::cout << "Error binding to the socket" << std::endl;
    //todo Add Exception
} else {
    char buffer[20];
    inet_ntop(AF_INET,  & serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, buffer, 20);
    std::cout << "Sucessfully bound the server to IP: " <<  buffer<< " and Port: " <<
    (uint) serv_addr.sin_port << std::endl;
}

listen(m_Socket.GetData(), 5);
```

Here is the Code for listening for a connection

> ```
>     std::cout << "Listening for a conection" << std::endl;
> ```

```
    socklen_t new_client;
    int clinet_id;


    sockaddr_in new_client_addr;
    clinet_id = accept(m_Socket.GetData(), (sockaddr*)&new_client_addr, &new_client);
    m_Client.SetData(clinet_id);

    if(0 > clinet_id ){
        std::cout << "ERROR Accepting new clinet" << clinet_id << std::endl;
    }else{
        std::cout << "Connection Established" << std::endl;
        m_ConnectedClient = true;
        start_sending();
    }
```

Then this detects a closing signal from a client and closes off the connection

> ```
> if (s.str() == NW_CLOSE_CONNECTION) {
>     std::cout << "Client wants to disconect" << std::endl;
>     close(m_Client.GetData());
>     m_ConnectedClient = false;
>     m_SendingBool = true;
> }
> ```
>
> Then the application returns to the listening for a connection code, but will not re-accept the connection.

The Client code is in python and is

> `Socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>   Socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
>   Socket.settimeout(.1)
>   while True:
>         message = Socket.recv(buffer_size)`
>   
>   Then when I end the application I call Socket.close()

Comment: Too minimal, I fear. What's posted looks correct. Off topic: I'd rename `SetData` and `GetData` to something like `SetSocket` to better describe what's going on to the casual eyeballing.

Comment: show more code, please--the rest of `listen`, preferrably

Comment: When did SO_REUSEPORT start to take a string instead of an int (0 vs 1)? It's usually `int optval = 1; setsockopt(sfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &optval, sizeof(optval));`, e.g. https://gist.github.com/carun/8146981

Comment: "receives an infinite amount of empty characters" indicates a bug in the client-side code.